# Help With Aligning Table and Using \Draw

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

Ok so I am wondering how I could get my code to look like the picture below. My issues are that if I use \draw using tikzpictures, I can make a line segment but it only goes over the S and then pushes the equation back. Also, the fractions are not all perfectly lined up. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccccccc}

$\frac{1}{2}S$ =& $\frac{1}{2}$ & & $- \frac{1}{4}$ & & $\frac{1}{6}$ & & $- \frac{1}{8}$ & & $\frac{1}{10}$ & & $- \frac{1}{12}$ & & $+ \cdots$ \\ \\


$+S$ = $1$ & $- \frac{1}{2}$ & $\frac{1}{3}$ & $- \frac{1}{4}$ & $\frac{1}{5}$ & $- \frac{1}{6}$ & $\frac{1}{7}$ & $- \frac{1}{8}$ & $\frac{1}{9}$ & $- \frac{1}{10}$ & $\frac{1}{11}$ & $- \frac{1}{12}$ & $\frac{1}{13}$ & $- \cdots$ \\ \\


$\frac{3}{2}S$ = $1$ & & $+ \frac{1}{3}$ & $- \frac{1}{2}$ & $\frac{1}{5}$ & & $\frac{1}{7}$ & $- \frac{1}{4}$ & $\frac{1}{9}$ & & $\frac{1}{11}$ & $-\frac{1}{6}$ & $\frac{1}{13}$ & $\cdots$

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: You don't need a hammersledge like tikz for that. Simply use `\midrule` from package `booktabs`.

Comment: Your code lacks many signs, for a start. Did you try with an `align` environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose to do that with an `alignat` environment, and `booktabs`. Note I replaced the fractionary coefficients with medium-sized fractions from `nccmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{8}
\mfrac{1}{2}S & =&\phantom{+ } \frac{1}{2} & &{} - \frac{1}{4} & &{}+ \frac{1}{6} & &{} - \frac{1}{8} & &{} + \frac{1}{10} & &{} - \frac{1}{12} & &{} + \cdots \\ \\
%
{}+S & = 1 &{} - \frac{1}{2} & + \frac{1}{3} &{} - \frac{1}{4} & + \frac{1}{5} &{}- \frac{1}{6} & +\frac{1}{7} &{} - \frac{1}{8} & + \frac{1}{9} &{}- \frac{1}{10} & + \frac{1}{11} &{} - \frac{1}{12} & + \frac{1}{13} &{} - \cdots \\
\addlinespace\cmidrule[0.5pt](l){1-16}\addlinespace
%%
\mfrac{3}{2}S & = 1 & & + \frac{1}{3} & - \frac{1}{2} & + \frac{1}{5} & & + \frac{1}{7} & - \frac{1}{4} & + \frac{1}{9} & & + \frac{1}{11} & -\frac{1}{6} & + \frac{1}{13} &\phantom{ + } \cdots
%
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]